# Allure TestOps: Cannot configure build server for job

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, allure

I am using Allure TestOps for E2E test reporting.
I'd like to be able to trigger test execution from Allure TestOps console (as explained [here](https://docs.qameta.io/allure-testops/integrations/github/)).

I have:

1. added GitHub integration
2. verified the GitHub integration's test connection (success)

I attempted to assign my GitHub integration to my GitHub Job. I followed the instructions outlined in the documentation

[image]

However, when I edited the job configuration and attempted to assign the build server, I encountered the following error:

`Request failed with status 400: Integration error: Expected job id in owner/repo/actions/workflows/id format, but found`

[image]

It appears that there may be some additional configuration required, but I was unable to locate this information in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the minimal configuration for running the job from Testops - https://docs.qameta.io/allure-testops/integrations/github/#31-declare-inputs-in-the-github-workflow

you should provide the job run ID as input to your workflow
I had the same issue until I implemented the workflow source from example